# How do I get a Lexmark t630 printer working?

Tags: printing, lexmark

I have a Lexmark t630. This is a big toner printer.

I could not find the ppd file for this printer because the website that used to have it, no longer works.

I was just wondering what the correct generic print driver would be for this printer.

The current on I put prints correctly but then after a while it'll only print random text.

Comment: Have you tried the driver Lexmark provided here: http://support.lexmark.com/index?docLocale=en_US&page=content&segType=driverSegmentLINUX_UNIX&id=DR21363&locale=EN&userlocale=EN_UK  http://support.lexmark.com/index?docLocale=en_US&page=content&segType=driverSegmentLINUX_UNIX&id=DR21363&locale=EN&userlocale=EN_UK

Comment: Yes but I need the ppd file because it is for a cups server.

Comment: I've searched the file on the Internet, but I couldn't find it,too. The only way you can get the file seems like waiting for a user who has the file ,looking this question. Maybe the PPD file for t620 can work for yours: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/70950457/LEXT630.PPD.
While the filename is lext630.ppd, it is for t620(I changed).

Comment: I have tried to install this driver that was provided but gave the same results. It prints but after a while just prints random letters.

Comment: You can want the file from cups.org by mailing to them. They can send the file if they have it.

Comment: I think I found the original ppd file: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/70950457/lexmark-lext630.ppd

Comment: Thank you so much! It seems to be working now. If I may ask, where did you get this file. I couldn't seem to find it.

Comment: I googled lext630.ppd, the second result was a github site. There was some code related to some ppd files. But there was only the names of the files. After that I have searched 'download' on that github directory, there was a download link for another file: http://www.artica.fr/download/openvpn-2.0.9-gui-1.0.3-install.exe. I edited the link to get the ppd: http://www.artica.fr/download/ppd/lexmark-lext630.ppd.gz and It worked.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the file that you need in order to get Lextmark T630 working(with mirrors):

- http://tny.cz/be4c97db
- https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/70950457/lexmark-lext630.ppd
- http://ubuntuone.com/1gurLwFc4pujCLyAZrXiRY
- http://www.artica.fr/download/ppd/lexmark-lext630.ppd.gz
- http://paste.ubuntu.com/5922895/

I hope one of them will be still alive when someone needs this file in the future.

Comment: I have installed this driver and it worked but now it is doing the same thing. Im starting to think it has to do with cups or the driver on windows that is sending the file. I have this printer connected through a cups server and is shared. On windows i have the t630 driver, I install it as a network printer with the windows t630 driver and print and it works. It then stop working after a while.

Comment: As I understood, the same problem is current to Windows, too, right?

Comment: Its persistent on windows. I havent printer from ubuntu other than a test page. Reason being is that it is a server. I have cups installed on the server. I have the printer connected to the cups server and is being shared of the network. The cups server requires a driver to print, this is why I needed the ppd. On windows I connect to the printer through the network. Windows asks for a driver and it install the correct one on its own. (lexmark). Could there be an incompatibility?

Comment: Since I've never shared a printer, I am stranger to what you wrote. Maybe there is a bug that needs reporting. You can mail about the problem to CUPS developers to get them to help you solve the problem. I am sorry I can't help you more, because I don't have enough information about CUPS.

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance. I will try to track the problem closer and if I cant solve it, ill report it as a bug. Thank you though, you were of great help.